# Safe way to get current day month and year in batch

Tags: windows, date, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script that will get the current day, month and year in a safe manner(i.e. independent of the date format). Unfortunately all the internet sources I have found propose something like:

```
   SET CURRENT_DATE=%DATE: =0%
   SET YEAR=%DATE:~-4%
   SET MONTH=%DATE:~3,2%
   SET DAY=%DATE:~5,2%
```

This will work if my date is in format yyyy/mm/dd or yyyy-mm-dd but will not if it is in format yy-mm-dd or some other format. Is there a safe way to get the year, month and day?

And one more question - is it possible to know what the day separator is(`/` in the first case and `-` in the other cases).

Comment: Use WMIC instead, [SO: Log Date/Time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7730453/463115)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you could retrieve the current settings from the registry (somewhere).
The format and also the separators.

But it's easier to use `wmic` instead, it has always the same format, the only drawback is, that it's take a bit of time, each time you start it.

Modified sample from [SO: Log Date/Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730453/463115)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
    if "%%B" NEQ "" (
        SET /A FDATE=%%F*10000+%%D*100+%%A
        SET /A FTIME=%%B*10000+%%C*100+%%E
    )
)
ECHO !FDATE! - !FTIME!
```

Comment: what does `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` do and why is it needed in this example?

Comment: It enables the delayed expansion (Wow!), best to read the help of `set /?`. And to say the truth: It isn't necessary here :-), You could simply change the echo to `echo %FDATE% - %FTIME%`

Answer (score 17):

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Here is a VBS solution:

```
  :: date time using WSH/VBS
  :: datetime.bat V4.2
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  ::
  :: This uses Windows Scripting Host to set variables to
  :: the current date/time/day/day_number/week_of_year etc
  :: for Win9x/ME/NT/W2K/XP/Vista/Win7/Win8 etc
  :: Thanks go to Todd Vargo for his scripting
  ::
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  @echo off
  set TmpFile="%temp%.\tmp.vbs"
  echo> %TmpFile% n=Now
  echo>>%TmpFile% With WScript
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set m1="   + monthname(month(n), true)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set m2="   + monthname(month(n), false)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set woy="  + CStr(datepart("ww", n))
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set year=" + CStr(Year(n))
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set yr="   + Right(Year(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set month="+ Right(100+Month(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set day="  + Right(100+Day(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set hour=" + Right(100+Hour(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set min="  + Right(100+Minute(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set sec="  + Right(100+Second(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set dow="  + WeekDayName(Weekday(n),1)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set dow2=" + WeekDayName(Weekday(n))
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set iso="  + CStr(1 + Int(n-2) mod 7)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set iso2=" + CStr(Weekday(n,2))
  echo>>%TmpFile% End With
  cscript //nologo "%temp%.\tmp.vbs" > "%temp%.\tmp.bat"
  call "%temp%.\tmp.bat"
  del  "%temp%.\tmp.bat"
  del  %TmpFile%
  set TmpFile=
  set stamp=%year%-%month%-%day%.%hour%_%min%_%sec%

  if not "%~1"=="" goto :EOF

  echo The year  is "%year%" or "%yr%"
  echo The month is "%month%" "%m1%" "%m2%"
  echo The day   is "%day%" "%dow%" "%dow2%"
  echo.
  echo ISO8601 Day-Of-Week number is "%iso%" and week of year is: "%woy%"

  echo.
  echo The time in hh:mm:ss is "%hour%:%min%:%sec%"
  echo The hour   is "%hour%"
  echo The minute is "%min%"
  echo The second is "%sec%"
  echo.

  echo The date and time stamp is "%stamp%"
  echo.
  echo date A yyyymmdd "%year%%month%%day%"
  echo date B mmddyyyy "%month%%day%%year%"
  echo date C ddmmyyyy "%day%%month%%year%"
  echo date D yymmdd   "%yr%%month%%day%"
  echo date E mmddyy   "%month%%day%%yr%"
  echo date F ddmmyy   "%day%%month%%yr%"
  pause
  :: datetime.bat
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 1):

**Extract Day, Month and Year (locale-independent)**

I wouldn't use WMIC since it's very high on resources and takes awhile to complete, especially on slower computers. The following script takes the users' localization from the registry, which is locale-independent. As far as I know is is the only batch solution that works. Of course you can also use a call to a VBScript but for me that's off-topic.

```
@echo off

::: Begin set date
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Determine short date format (independent from localization) from registry
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3-5 delims=- " %%L in ( '2^>nul reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sShortDate"' ) do ( 

    :: Since we can have multiple (short) date formats we only use the first char from the format in a new variable
    set "_L=%%L" && set "_L=!_L:~0,1!" && set "_M=%%M" && set "_M=!_M:~0,1!" && set "_N=%%N" && set "_N=!_N:~0,1!"

    :: Now assign the date values to the new vars
    for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/-. " %%D in ( "%date%" ) do ( set "!_L!=%%D" && set "!_M!=%%E" && set "!_N!=%%F" )
)


:: Print the values as is
echo.
echo This is the original date string --^> %date%
echo These are the splitted values    --^> Day: %d%, Month:%m%, Year: %y%.
echo.

endlocal
```

**Extract only the Year**

For a script I wrote I wanted only to extract the year (locale-independent) so I came up with this oneliner as I couldn't find any solution.  It uses the 'DATE' var, multiple delimiters and checks for a number greater than 31. That then will be the current year. It's low on resources in contrast to some of the other solutions.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions

for /f " tokens=2-4 delims=-./ " %%D in ( "%date%" ) do ( if %%D gtr 31 ( set "_YEAR=%%D" ) else ( if %%E gtr 31 ( set "_YEAR=%%E" ) else ( if %%F gtr 31 ( set "_YEAR=%%F" ) ) ) )

echo And the year is... %_YEAR%.
echo.

endlocal
```