# sed.exe -e expression #1, unknown command

Tags: linux, windows, sed

First of all, sorry if it is duplicated but I am a totally newbie on Sed. I was assigned to investigate an error log but after fixing it based on some tutorials my problem is still not solved.

Here is the original code:

```
@sed.exe -i "s/\(.*CONFIG_PROJECT_SW_DATE_VERSION=\"\).*\(\"\)/\1%date:~2,2%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%\2/g/" .\ghsproj_du2_avc_src.gpj
```

after running, I received the following error:

```
03-27 13:22:43 sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 53: unknown option to `s'
03-27 13:22:43 Could Not Find C:\jenkins-slave\workspace\project\work\build\ghs\sed*
```

I have read some solutions like remove the blank space between -i and s command or enter a "/" at the end but nothing works so far.

P/S: I ran this on Windows 10 environment.

Comment: The slash after the `g` modifier is a mistake — possibly even _the_ mistake.  Removing the space between `-i` and the `s///g` command would not help; it would confuse things even more.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the answer, I have edited the code and removed the backslash but it would return another error: 

sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'

Comment: Character position 53 is the `%` at the start of `%date:~2,2%`, which is presumably a variable substitution in DOS `cmd` scripting.  Do `echo %data:~2,2%` (or its equivalent — show the result of the expansion somehow) and there will (almost certainly) be a slash in the result, and that slash is throwing your command off.  Adjust the numbers accordingly; test the separate `%date:…%` bits first before building them into the `sed` command.

Comment: Note that you currently have `"s/…/…/g/"`, even after your edit.  You need `"s/…/…/g"` only.  Those are slashes, not backslashes.  But I'm fairly confident that your date substring operation is what's causing you grief.  You could also try simply echoing the command as a whole to see what `sed` is being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (GNU sed):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%a"
sed.exe "s@\(.*CONFIG_PROJECT_SW_DATE_VERSION=\x22\).*\(\x22\)@\1%dt:~2,2%%dt:~4,2%%dt:~6,2%\2@g" file
```

Change the two `%a` to `%%a` if you are putting them in a batch file.
I removed `-i` switch, add it back when you tested that the output is okay.

Several things to be considered:

- You are using `sed` on `cmd` or in batch file, thus be careful about the double quotes and the escaping. So I just changed the quotes inside with `\x22` which is another way to refer to characters by their ASCII code. (GNU sed feature).
- On `cmd` or in batch file, `%date:~2,2%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%` does not guaranteed to be `YYMMDD`, depending on different Locale settings, they can have `/` inside, maybe it's the cause of your error. I tried another way to get the date, copied the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20841873/5403468).
- You can change the delimiter of `s` command to other character, I changed to `@` here.
- There should be no `/` after the `g` flag.

Example:

```
> type file
var CONFIG_PROJECT_SW_DATE_VERSION="whatever"

> @for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do @set "dt=%a"
> sed.exe "s@\(.*CONFIG_PROJECT_SW_DATE_VERSION=\x22\).*\(\x22\)@\1%dt:~2,2%%dt:~4,2%%dt:~6,2%\2@g" file
var CONFIG_PROJECT_SW_DATE_VERSION="190327"
```