# how can i get this script to run without user input

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup

I’m trying to make this batch script automatic. The drive letter changes and i cant find a way in window to force it to use the same one each time. im not using the %date% environment variable because i need the date format to be like this: "YYYY_MM_DD"

Is there any way I can i get this script to run without user input?

```
    @echo off
    set /p "Drive_Letter=Enter Drive letter.>"
    set /p "BKDate=Enter date.>"
    cd\
    %Drive_Letter%:
    cd %Drive_Letter%:\Backup\
    md BK_%BKDate%
    cd\
    Robocopy /E c:\users\%username%\Dropbox\ %Drive_Letter%:\Backup\BK_%BKDate% *
    cd %Drive_Letter%:\Backup
    dir /s %Drive_Letter%:\Backup\BK_%BKDate%% >> LOG_%BKDate%.txt
```

Comment: regarding the date format, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083366/format-file-date-yyyymmdd-in-batch

Comment: you may find this useful for trying to just find which drive is being used instead of having to enter it: http://superuser.com/questions/527252/how-to-make-a-batch-file-to-search-all-drives

Comment: Is the batch file located on the USB drive?

Comment: no the batch is in my dropbox folder. Would putting it on the usb drive make a diffrence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses:

`robocopy` inside a subroutine to get the current date (an error is forced to get the time stamp of the error in `yyyy/mm/dd` format)

`mountvol` to enumerate the defined drives

`vol` to test drive accesibility

It will search for a "flag" folder (the backup folder) in the drives to determine which to use

Once all the information is retrived, the adecuated robocopy command is used.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getDriveLetter "\Backup\bk*" drive
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo Drive not found
        goto :eof
    )

    call :getTodayDate   today
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo Date retrieval error
        goto :eof
    )

    set "BKDate=%today:/=_%"
    set "source=c:\users\%username%\Dropbox"
    set "target=%drive%:\Backup\BK_%BKDate%"

    robocopy "%source%" "%target%" /e
    dir /s "%target%" > "%drive%:\Backup\LOG_%BKDate%.txt"

    endlocal
    exit /b

:getTodayDate returnVar
    set "%~1=" & for /f %%a in (
        'robocopy "|" "." "%~nx0" /njh /r:0 /nocopy /l'
    ) do set "%~1=%%a" & exit /b 0
    exit /b 1

:getDriveLetter folderToTest returnVar
    set "%~2=" & for /f "tokens=1 delims=: " %%a in (
        'mountvol ^| find ":\"' 
    ) do vol %%a: >nul 2>&1 && (if exist "%%a:%~1" set "%~2=%%a" & exit /b 0)
    exit /b 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do want you want.

```
@echo off
Z:
cd Z:\Backup\
Rem Get Day,Mth & Year from %Date%
set Day=%Date:~0,2%
set Mth=%Date:~3,2%
set Yr=%Date:~6,4%
md BK_%Yr%_%Mth%_%Day%

Robocopy /E %userprofile%\Dropbox\ Z:\Backup\BK_%Day%_%Mth%_%Yr% *

dir /s Z:\Backup\BK_%Yr%_%Mth%_%Day%% >> LOG_%Yr%_%Mth%_%Day%.txt
```

This [Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2e46e15b-c67b-4404-8e8c-5d7a51508f84/can-you-force-a-usb-hdd-to-always-keep-the-same-drive-letter?forum=w7itprogeneral) will show you how to force the USB to use the same drive letter each time it is connected